# Стилизация input

Tags: javascript, css, html5, дата, input

Со стилизацией форм вечные проблемы. Сейчас столкнулся с необходимостью по-особенному выводить дату. Можно ли как-то изменить шрифт, цвета и убрать из поля год? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите ваш код, пожалуйста.

Comment: @shugich  вот, простая структура  https://codepen.io/gunslighter__od/pen/BRrOyV

Comment: Так, и что с этой структурой? Вы не знаете как сверстать эту картинку или что? Не понятно что именно не получается :-(

Comment: @shugich это должен быть input [type="date"]. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы при выборе даты она выводилась таким образом, как на картинке, а не стандартным видом?

Comment: А менять дату моно только при помощи календаря?

Comment: @shugich  ну можно и вручную, все равно. но с календаря нужно обязательно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот ваше решение. Идея в функции changeDate() в которую вы передаете дату, выбранную в календаре. Полная дата записывается в скрытый инпут, чтобы ее можно было прочитать формой. Но отображается она отдельно при помощи обычных блоков.

```js
function changeDate(date) {
  // Записываем дату в скрытй инпут
  document.querySelector('input[name="date"]').value = date;
  
  // Сохраняем месяц в переменную в необходимом формате
  var month = date.toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long'})
  
  // Меняем месяц в DOM
  document.querySelector('.date__month').innerHTML = month;
  
  // Соххраняем день месяца
  var day = date.getDate();
  
  // Меняем день в DOM
  document.querySelector('.date__day').innerHTML = day;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var now = new Date();
  changeDate(now);
})
```

```css
.date {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.date__day {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form class="header__form">
  <input type="hidden" name="date">  
  <div class="date">
    <div class="date__day">10</div>
    <div class="date__month">апрель</div>
  </div>
</form>

<button>Изменить дату</button>
```